# Group entries by custom field from a relationship field

Tags: channel-entries, relationships

I've got the following code inside a channel entry tag. It works fine, but i just want to group it by {which-day} and then orderby another custom field.

```
{parents field="lessons"}
    <tr>
        <td>{parents:title}</td>
        <td>{parents:day"}</td>
    </tr>
{/parents}
```

Is it possible to do this natively?